# Giving space between digits of binary string

Tags: c++, binary, c++14

Suppose I have a string of Binary number, eg. 1110001110010101 , and I want to store this number in a string.

Now I want to separate these 1's and 0's so that I can work over them. How shall I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a space in between every four characters in this output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302820/how-do-i-put-a-space-in-between-every-four-characters-in-this-output)

Answer (score 3):

As you're working with C++ your string is stored in array and using index you can access or you can use iterator

```
string str = "mystring";
 
   // Declaring iterator
    std::string::iterator it;

    // Declaring reverse iterator
    std::string::reverse_iterator it1;

    // Displaying string
    cout << "The string using forward iterators is : ";
    for (it=str.begin(); it!=str.end(); it++)
    cout << *it;

    cout << endl;


    // Displaying reverse string
    cout << "The reverse string using reverse iterators is : ";

    for (it1=str.rbegin(); it1!=str.rend(); it1++)
    cout << *it1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always go for the naive approach, allocate a new string (almost) twice the size of the input string, and fill it one character at a time.

For example:

```
std::string expand(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string new_str;

    size_t size = str.size();
    new_str.resize(size*2-1);

    for (size_t n = 0; n < size-1; n++)
    {
        new_str[n*2+0] = str[n];
        new_str[n*2+1] = ' ';
    }

    new_str[size*2-2] = str[size-1];

    return new_str;
}
```